# PivotItem.Visible seems always true

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following pivottable:

*Rowlables:*
- Store
- OrderID
- Article

*Columnlables:*
- status

*Value Lables:*
- Quantity

Above the pivot, I have a slicer for **StoreGroup**. For this example, let's state that every store is either in group **A** or **B** and that i have set the slicer to show **A** only. 1 order does not exist in multiple stores.

In VBA, I want to loop through all the remaining orders. Here's my code:

```
Sub TEST()
  Dim pvt as PivotTable
  Set pvt = Sheets("Pivot").PivotTables("Orders")

  Dim pvf as PivotField
  Set pvf = pvt.PivotFields("OrderID")

  Dim pvi as PivotItem
  For Each pvi in pvf.PivotItems
    If pvi.Visible = True Then
      Debug.Print pvi.Value
    End if
  Next pvi
End Sub
```

When I run this code, all existing OrderID's are listed, even those with StoreGroup **B**.

My question: How do I know if the order is hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Function ItemIsActive(pvtItem As PivotItem) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    ItemIsActive = Not pvtItem.DataRange.EntireRow.Hidden
Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    ItemIsActive = False
End Function
```

This code checks if the datarange row is hidden

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer. Avoid posting code-only answers without proper description.